# AWS CloudWatch Trigger at Start Time Repeating Till End Time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda function that needs to get triggers on Saturdays 2pm, 2:10pm, 2:20pm, 2:30pm... 4pm

I know CloudWatch Events can trigger lambda functions at a certain time. However, I am unsure a single CloudWatch Event can trigger at the times I want. Is there any way to do this without having to create 12 CloudWatch Events to trigger the same lambda?

Comment: CW uses `crone` expressions for scheduling. `cron` can do something like this (list of values for repetition using `,`) [check here](https://linuxize.com/post/scheduling-cron-jobs-with-crontab/). Though don't know if CW has full support for `cron` or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CW event schedule expression would be `cron(0/10 14-16 ? * SAT *)`

Runs every 10th minute on Saturdays between 2PM and 3:50PM UTC. Detailed explanation can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html#CronExpressions).

Comment: Good to know that CW has full support for cron expressions.